# ExpressionEngine Manual Entry Import

Tags: php, mysql, expressionengine

I have an XML feed from an old website which contains news articles. I have to import these articles in to my new ExpressionEngine site. I intend to do so by parsing the XML and writing some PHP to do a simple insert.

I am quite confused about ExpressionEngines' schema, which table are the entries stored in? Also if there is a (free) extension to do this that would be great.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All ExpressionEngine posts are stored in the exp_channel_data (2.x) or exp_weblog_data (1.x) table.

For EE1.x I found this:

- [Import Data into ExpressionEngine](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/import-data-into-expressionengine)

I could not find a free plugin to do an import for EE2.x.

For EE2.x I found these:

- [Importer](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/importer/) - commercial
- [DataGrab](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab) - commercial

**Edit:**

Found this free plugin that might be able to help you with an import in EE2.x:

[MX Tool Box](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-tool-box)

Comment: +1 for DataGrab, an add-on which has saved my hide many, many times. Well worth the price!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, *magzalez's* answer is incomplete - only custom field data is stored in `exp_channel_data`.

You also need to look at:

- `exp_channel_titles`
- `exp_members` (`exp_channel_titles` uses an `author_id` column, which has to correspond to an entry in `exp_members`
- `exp_category_posts`, which is a relationship table connecting the `entry_id` from `exp_channel_titles` and the `cat_id` from `exp_categories`